# Is my Quaternion multiplication correct?

Tags: quaternions

I'm trying to multiply 2 Quaternion equations but I'm not sure if I'm multiplying them correctly. Here are the 2 equations:

$_1 = 2 −  +  + 3$

$_2 = −1 +  + 4 − 2k$

and here is how I've multiplied these 2 equations:

$$q_1q_2 = ((2)(-1) - (-1)(1) - (1)(4) - (3)(-2))\\ + ((2)(1) - (-1)(-1) - (1)(-2) - (3)(4))i \\+
       ((2)(4) - (-1)(-2) - (1)(-1) - (3)(1))j\\ +
       ((2)(-2) - (-1)(4) - (1)(1) - (3)(-1))k$$

When simplifying this, I get:

$$q_1q_2 = -8i + 4j + 2k $$

But calculating this using online counters I seem to be getting different results, have I calculated this correctly?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704032/how-do-i-solve-quaternion-equations), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703419/resources-for-quaternion-equations).

Answer (score 1):

This table will help you

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 \cdot &  1  &  i  &  j  &  k \\ \hline
    1  &  1  &  i  &  j  &  k \\ \hline
    i  &  i  & -1  &  k  & -j \\ \hline
    j  &  j  & -k  & -1  &  i \\ \hline
    k  &  k  &  j  & -i  & -1 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

So for example

$$
ji = -k
$$